# Kedro viz failing

Tags: python, pycharm, kedro

I am using kedro 0.19.1 on PyCharm. I have installed kedro and kedro viz. When I run 'kedro viz run' it is failing.

Is there any additional steps I need to follow here?

Error: kedro.framework.cli.utils.kedroCLiError: func: <function _check_viz_up at ...>, didn't return True within specified timeout

Thanks.

I tried kedro viz run and was expecting a pipeline graph for my kedro pipeline.

Comment: it might be a problem with your `_check_viz_up` configuration

Answer (score 0):

Kedro 0.19 works with `kedro-viz~=7.0.0`. Try to downgrade:

```
pip install kedro-viz~=7.0.0
```